# Finding all commands in Symfony 3 console app

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, console-application

I'm creating a Symfony 3 console app and trying to stay away from using the entire framework, relying on just components here and there. I've extended the default `Symfony\Component\Console\Application` class to allow for a container, and into that container I'm loading `app/config/services.yml` in an attempt to auto-discover all the commands in my app. The config file looks like this:

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: false

    vagabond.command.config.get:
        class: Vagabond\Command\Config\Get
        tags: ['console.command']
    vagabond.command.config.set:
        class: Vagabond\Command\Config\Set
        tags: ['console.command']
    vagabond.command.site.add:
        class: Vagabond\Command\Site\Add
        tags: ['console.command']
    vagabond.command.site.edit:
        class: Vagabond\Command\Site\Edit
        tags: ['console.command']
    vagabond.command.site.remove:
        class: Vagabond\Command\Site\Remove
        tags: ['console.command']
```

In my `Application` class I've overridden `getDefaultCommands()` like so:

```
protected function getDefaultCommands()
{
    $commands = parent::getDefaultCommands();

    foreach ($this->container->findTaggedServiceIds('console.command') as $commandId => $command) {
        $commands[] = $this->container->get($commandId);
    }

    return $commands;
}
```

And that all works! All the commands I've specified in my `services.yml` file are loaded. But...I'd like to be able to use resource loading instead of manually specifying each command (otherwise I may as well put them in my shell command using `new \Vagabond\Command\Config\Get`). I tried putting this in my `services.yml` file:

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: false

    vagabond.command.config.get:
        class: Vagabond\Command\Config\Get
        tags: ['console.command']
    vagabond.command.config.set:
        class: Vagabond\Command\Config\Set
        tags: ['console.command']
    vagabond.command.site.add:
        class: Vagabond\Command\Site\Add
        tags: ['console.command']
    vagabond.command.site.edit:
        class: Vagabond\Command\Site\Edit
        tags: ['console.command']
    vagabond.command.site.remove:
        class: Vagabond\Command\Site\Remove
        tags: ['console.command']

    Vagabond\Command\Config\:
        resource: '../../src/Command/Config/*'
        tags: ['console.command2']
```

Then I modified my `Application` class to find the `console.command2` tags instead. Got this error:

`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ReflectionException: Class  does not exist in ~/Documents/projects/vagabond/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/ContainerBuilder.php:1083`

For the eagle-eyed, that's two spaces after `Class` - turns out when I use resources, the `Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Definition` instance for the discovered class has its private `$class` value set as `null`, so when the app tries to use reflection to create the class, it uses `null` as the actual class name it's trying to create.

My question is this, then: is there any way to use that `resource` key to grab all my commands at once, *and* ensure that they have all the right info necessary to be instantiated on demand?